# Want to display only columns that have values

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to display columns that have values in then, but the code displays every column. The if statement is ignored don't know what am doing wrong.
There are two tables Person_Permission and Person. I am selecting all the columns in Person_Permission that have values, after getting those column names I am using those columns to select from Person table.

```
USE [exampleProject]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[list_col_notNull]    Script Date: 2016/04/18 11:53:51 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[list_col_notNull](@username VARCHAR(20))
AS

    DECLARE @col VARCHAR(255), @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT * INTO #table FROM Person_Permissions
    WHERE userName = @username

    DECLARE getinfo CURSOR FOR
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Person_Permissions'

    SET @cmd = 'SELECT '

    OPEN getinfo

    FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #table WHERE @col IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @cmd = @cmd + RTRIM(@col) + ','
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
    END

    CLOSE getinfo
    DEALLOCATE getinfo
    SET @cmd = LEFT(@cmd, LEN(@cmd) -1) + ' FROM [Person]'
    select * from #table
    EXEC(@cmd)
    SELECT(@cmd)
```

Comment: What's the end goal?  Can you not hide empty columns in the display layer rather than generating dynamic SQL?  Or are you dealing with a bad structure that does not have data normalized properly?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output (and expected/actual generated query)? You are selecting columns from `Person_Permissions` and your final query selects from `Person`, is that correct?

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #table WHERE @col IS NOT NULL` - evaluates the `@col` variable, which is never `null`. Maybe you need some dynamic query there too. But this gets bloated. Maybe you'll be better off hiding the columns in a different app layer.

Comment: might help you http://forums.asp.net/t/1931738.aspx?Hide+Column+With+Null+Values+using+SQL+server+2005

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example that does exactly what you are looking for by checking the length of all values in the column in a while statement so this should be more efficient than the cursor.

```
USE [Test]
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE Name = 'Person_Permissions' AND Type = 'U')
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Person_Permissions]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

--Creating a table to test this out
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person_Permissions](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Department] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

--Setting some null data
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Person_Permissions](FirstName,LastName,UserName,Department)
VALUES('Joe','Smith','JSmith',null)
GO


DECLARE @TempColumns TABLE
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
ColumnName varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @TempColumns
 SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Person_Permissions'

DECLARE @Idx int = (select count(*) from @TempColumns)    
DECLARE @ColumnNameSelect varchar(max) = ''

WHILE @Idx > 0
BEGIN

DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(100) = (select ColumnName  from @TempColumns where ID = @Idx)
DECLARE @ValueLength int    
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500) = N'@ValueLengthOUT int OUTPUT';
--using a sub query to check length of all values if null make it zero
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) = ('SELECT @ValueLengthOUT=ISNULL(SUM(A.ValueLength),0) FROM (SELECT LEN([' + @ColumnName + ']) ValueLength FROM [dbo].[Person_Permissions]) AS A' )

exec sp_executesql @Sql, @ParmDefinition, @ValueLengthOUT=@ValueLength OUTPUT;

--if there is a value for the column use that column in our select
IF (@ValueLength > 0)
BEGIN
 SET @ColumnNameSelect = @ColumnNameSelect + @ColumnName + ','
END

SET @Idx = @Idx - 1
END

DECLARE @cmd varchar(max)= 'SELECT ' + (SELECT LEFT(@ColumnNameSelect, LEN(@ColumnNameSelect) -1)) + ' FROM [Person_Permissions]'

EXEC (@cmd)
```